# How do I change the date of all photos in one event to exactly the same date?

Tags: iphoto

iPhoto changes dates of photos relatively. For example, I have two photos in an event. One has date 1-Mar and the other one 2-Mar. If I select them both and change the date to one day before, the new dates will be 28-Feb and 1-Mar. How do I change a bunch of photos to exactly the same date, regardless of their original date in iPhoto?

Answer (score 0):

In the menu, select Photos → Batch Change (<kbd>⬆</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>). Choose "Date" from the select box, modify it, and all of the photos' dates will be adjusted to the date you set.